# Minecraft proxy service and python script not working as intended

Tags: python, server, proxy, raspberry-pi, portforwarding

I have created a service using systemd in Ubuntu 22.04.02. This service is a simple service that starts up on boot up and runs a python script I created. The Python script is made to do a few things. I wanted to create a script on my raspberry pi 4.0 8gb that monitored all incoming network traffic to people trying to connect to a few different minecraft servers.

```
import paramiko
import subprocess
import socket
import psutil
import time 

#Function to detatch from a screen/session
def detach_from_screen(session_name):
    subprocess.run(["screen", "-S", session_name, "-X", "detach"])

#Function to attatch to a screen/session
def attach_to_screen(session_name):
    subprocess.run(["screen", "-r", session_name])

#Function to start a server in it's own screen session
def start_server(s_folder_name,exc_process):
    subprocess.run(["screen", "-dmS", s_folder_name, "bash", exc_process])
    detach_from_screen(s_folder_name)

#Function to stop a server in it's own screen session
def stop_server(s_folder_name,exc_process):
    attach_to_screen(s_folder_name)
    subprocess.run(["screen", "-r", s_folder_name, ])

#Function to check if the server pc is on or not, then turns on PC if it's off. 
def ping_serverPC():
    ip_address = '192.168.1.130'
    attempt = subprocess.run(['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', ip_address], capture_output=True)
    if attempt.returncode == 0:
        print('Server PC is on.')
    else:
        print('Server PC is off. Sending magic packet now.')
        from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet
        mac_address = ''
        send_magic_packet(mac_address)

#Function to check if a server is running with a specific server name
def check_server_running(exc_process):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
        if proc.memory_info['name'] == exc_process:
            return True
    return False

#Function to forward connection to the appropriate Minecraft server from proxy port
def forward_connection(server_conn, proxy_port):
    server_ip = '192.168.1.130' #Internal IP of the server PC
    server_port = 25567 # Default Minecraft server port

    if proxy_port == 8111:
        server_port = 25567 #Fabric server port 
    elif proxy_port == 8222:
        server_port = 25568 #Create server port
    elif proxy_port == 8333:
        server_port = 25569 #Enigmatica server port

    try:
        server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_sock.connect((server_ip, server_port))

        #Forward player's connection to the Minecraft server
        forward_thread = socket._socketobject.makefile(server_conn, server_sock)
        reverse_thread = socket._socketobject.makefile(server_sock, server_conn)
        forward_thread.write("HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-agent: PyProxy\r\n\r\n")
        forward_thread.flush()     


        # Start forwarding data between the client and Minecraft server
        while True:
            data = forward_thread.read(8192)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            reverse_thread.write(data)
            reverse_thread.flush()

        # Close the connections
        forward_thread.close()
        reverse_thread.close()
        server_conn.close()
        server_sock.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while forwarding connection: {e}")



#define variables sockets for each individual minecraft server


server1_port = 25567 #port for fabric server
server1_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server1_socket.bind(('192.168.1.120',server1_port))
server1_socket.listen(1)

server2_port = 25568 #port for create modded server
server2_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server2_socket.bind(('192.168.1.120',server2_port))
server2_socket.listen(1)

server3_port = 25569 #port for enigmatica server
server3_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server3_socket.bind(('192.168.1.120',server3_port))
server3_socket.listen(1)


# SSH configuration
host = '192.168.1.130'
username = 'dealbreacker'
password = '157984632'

# Connect to the server PC
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)



# Execute commands or perform monitoring
while True:
    # Example: execute a command on the server PC
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
    output = stdout.read().decode()

    #The following code is for recieving connection attempts to each individual server

    #Accepting connection to fabric server
    server1_conn, server1_addr = server1_socket.accept()
    print(f"Connection established for server 1 from : {server1_addr}")

    #Accepting connection to create server
    server2_conn, server2_addr = server2_socket.accept()
    print(f"Connection established for server 2 from : {server2_addr}")

    #Accepting connection to enigmatica server
    server3_conn, server3_addr = server3_socket.accept()
    print(f"Connection established from server 3 from : {server3_addr}")


    #Check if a connection attempt was made for the fabric server
    if server1_conn:
        #Check to see if server PC is on
        ping_serverPC()
        time.sleep(60)
        #Start/Connect to server if not already running 
        if not check_server_running('java -Xms6G -Xmx6G -jar fabric-server-mc1.18.1-loader.0.14.5-launcher.0.10.2.jar nogui'):
            start_server('Cousins Survival', '/home/dealbreacker/Servers from PI/fabric_server_1.18.1_survival/start.sh')
            #process for connection
            time.sleep(120)
        
        #Forward the players connection to the Fabric server
        forward_connection(server1_conn, 8111)

    #Check if a connection attempt was made for the create server 
    if server2_conn:
        #Check to see if server PC is on
        ping_serverPC()
        time.sleep(60)
        #Start/Connect to server if not already running 
        if not check_server_running('java @user_jvm_args.txt @libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.18.2-40.1.60/unix_args.txt'):
            start_server('Create: Above and Beyond', '/home/dealbreacker/Servers from PI/create_modded_server_2/run.sh')
            #process for connection   
            time.sleep(120)

        #Forward the players connection to the create server
        forward_connection(server2_conn, 8222)

    #Check if a connection attempt was made for the enigmatica server
    if server3_conn:
        #Check to see if server PC is on
        ping_serverPC()
        time.sleep(60)
        #Start/Connect to server if not already running 
        if not check_server_running('/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx12G'):
            start_server('Enigmatca Expert' , '/home/dealbreacker/Servers from PI/enigmatica_2_expert_serv/ServerStartLinux.sh')
            #process for connection   
            time.sleep(120)

        #Forward the players connection to the enigmatica server
        forward_connection(server3_conn, 8333)

    


    #The following code is for monitoring and running the multiple MC servers on the server PC
```

The main concept is that the raspberry pi would run 24/7, but the desktop PC that hosted the servers would not be on unless the raspberry pi received a connection attempt to one of the three servers. If it received one, it would boot up the server PC using WOL, and then turn on the corresponding server the player was trying to connect too. I ended up turning my rpi into a proxy server that monitored incoming traffic on it's port, and then tried forwarding the players connection to the minecraft server's ip and port. I have a domain and a DNS that the players use to connect, and the DNS has A records that point to the routers/raspberry pi's public IP, and SRV records that point towards the ports the servers should/will run on. Furthermore, on my router itself, my rpi is ported 3 times (one for each server) with it's local ip and 3 proxy ports, 8111,8222,and 8333 for simplicity. When I ran the service, It successfully booted up the python script, but when I tried to connect to one of the three servers that were set up, there was nothing. None of the servers boot up and there was no connection.

I have tried to restart services and all sorts of other techniques. Even used chatGPT to see if it could find an issue. Nothing... Any help at all would be extremely appreciated, as I spent so much time writing this code and would be sad if it all went to waste. Thank you all

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.